# Gauge invariance of a lagrangian density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Considering the following Lagrangian density:
$$\mathcal{L} = -A_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu\nu}$$
with $A_{\mu\nu}$ a generic field.

I have to check if the action is invariant under:
$$A_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow A_{\mu\nu} + \partial_\mu \epsilon_\nu(x) - \partial_\nu\epsilon_\mu(x)$$
I have observed that the variation of the action can be written as:
$$\Delta S = \int d^4x \partial_\mu V^\mu(x)$$
where $V_\mu(x)$ is a function of $\epsilon_\mu(x)$.

is it correct to observe that this last term does not modify the equations of motion and therefore the previous transformation is a symmetry or the variation of the action must be zero?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. When total derivatives such as $\partial_{\mu} V^{\mu}$ appear in the Lagrangian it's assumed that they vanish at infinity, in which case they do not contribute. This is the case in $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$. However, if you don't assume your fields vanish at infinity, such as when your manifold in question actually has a boundary, total derivatives can still contribute to the field equations. In general relativity, for example, these are known as [Gibbons-Hawking-York terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbons%E2%80%93Hawking%E2%80%93York_boundary_term) and appear when we choose our spacetime to be a manifold with boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if we are on the Minkowski space which has no boundary, I can assume that the gauge parameter tends to zero at infinity and therefore the transformation is a symmetry, correct?

Comment: Most likely. There are some cases, such as the [BPST instanton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPST_instanton) where you explicitly take effects of the boundary into account by compactifying $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ to $S^4$, but in a basic gauge theory context you should be able to assume it vanishes at infinity.